# How do I return consecutive rows in an R data frame

Tags: r

For example, my data frame will have a column named a with the number `100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 110, 111, 112`

I would only like to return the rows that have consecutive numbers at least 3 times

So my final output will be the rows that have `100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112`

Second update:
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,A,b,4,10,2,3,4)
v1 is a column in the df and the class of v1 is actually character
by using your method, it does not actually return the result I want. Would you please provide any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to construct a logical vector with `diff`, `split` and get the elements that are of `length` 3 or greater

```
lst1 <- split(v1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v1) != 1)))
unname(unlist(lst1[lengths(lst1) >= 3]))
#[1] 100 101 102 110 111 112
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 110, 111, 112)
```

Comment: For this to succeed you had first better make sure the data frame is sorted by the column.

Comment: @whuber it works with `v2 <- c(100, 101, 102, 98, 99, 100, 104, 105, 66, 67, 68, 110, 111, 112)`  can you please show an example that is not working.  Then, I can update. thanks

Comment: That succeeded *only* because you kept the blocks intact and sorted in the input.  Any other order will fail.  Try `v1 <- sort(c(100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 110, 111, 112), decreasing=TRUE)` as an extreme example.

Comment: @whuber i understand your post.  I was thinking that the order is the same order of occurrence instead of the sorted one.  I would assume the OP respond to your point. thanks